# How to increase the width of mat-dialog-actions in Angular 8

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I need to use the entire dialog window space to utilize by both cancel and save buttons.

Can anyone help me on this?

[image]

Comment: Need more details! What you have tried? What is not working? etc or sample demo to reproduce an issue or behavior! also refer [this](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview)

Comment: I attached screenshot where i need to use the whole window space for both buttons.

Comment: if you want buttons individually one below the other, make a div per button and define a class with width as 100%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your buttons are contained in a `mat-dialog-actions` `div`, you can do this by simply adding the following definition to the CSS file of your dialog.

```
button {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Please have a look at the following [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2jmzh6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdialog-overview-example.html)